# How do you concatenate two active record results to return a new result that can further be filtered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

Imagine the scenario...

```
#models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :accounts, :conditions => { :active => 1 }
end

#models/account.rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    def public_accounts
        Account.all :conditions => { public => true }
    end
end
```

Now imagine I want to concatenate User(:id).accounts with Account.public_accounts to show a list of all accounts available to a user.

So you'd think I'd be able to update the User model to look like this.

```
#models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :accounts, :conditions => { :active => 1 }

    def all_accounts
        self.accounts + Account.public
    end
end
```

However, now I won't be able to use the all() method since it's no longer of that type of object.

In the controller I'd like to do this...

```
#controllers/accounts_controller.rb
def search_all
    User.find(params[:user_id]).all_accounts.all(
        :offset => params[:offset],
        :limit => params[:limit]
    )
end
```

Thoughts?

Update #1:
Scope's won't work for my scenario.  I simplified my scenario to try and get my point across.  As stated I need a way to combine two active record results and retain the ability to further filter them in my controller.

So the question is, "Why?"  The reason is, I am trying to combine two sets of records to form a complete collection and one of the collections is not associated with the user at all.

I have refactored the above scenario to try and show a more precise example without getting overly complicated.

Comment: Why would you not be able to use `all` when the method you have added is `all_accounts`?

Comment: KandadaBoggu, try it.  It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jklina's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437874/how-do-you-concatenate-two-active-record-results-to-return-a-new-result-that-can/7438045#7438045) is correct, it's best to use scopes in this situation. Scopes provide a sugary syntax and are more readable. I'll elaborate on the setup:

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many :accounts
end

class Account < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :active, where(:active => true)
  scope :inactive, where(:active => false)
end
```

You would then access the account scopes as jklina showed: `User.find(1).accounts.active`, etc.
Accessing all of a user's accounts like: `User.find(1).accounts`.

UPDATE:

I fixed some mistakes and added more below.

Based on the updates to your question, I think you need to make the `public` method a method on the class:

```
class Accounts < AR::Base
  ...
  # This is essentially a scope anyways
  def self.public
    where(:public => true)
  end
end

class User < AR::Base
  ...
  # This should return all the users accounts
  # and any public accounts
  def all_accounts
    Account.where("user_id = ? OR public is true", self.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: I didn't even consider doing a where in the User. It's a great idea, unfortunately it doesn't look like 'public is true' will work. It's throwing an error when I try and do that

Comment: I will try and go back and do that.  I actually learned about the self. declaration on the method after doing this.  That's probably all that was missing.

Comment: Important note, in Rails 4 scope requires symbol and a lambda, this is supported il rails 3 too, so I suggest to use `scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }` to keep it working (and it's more consistent with more complex scopes).

Answer (score 4):

This might be a good scenario to use [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

You can define active and inactive scopes in the Account model and then use the following:

```
User.accounts
User.accounts.active
User.accounts.inactive
```

You can even chain scopes together, so you could do something like:

```
User.accounts.active.paid_up
```

Comment: My question was and still remains how to concatenate to active record results.  Since that wasn't answered I made modifications to my scenario to try and show closer to why I "believe" I need to do this.  Thanks, but I'd have used scopes if I could have.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at the return values in the chain:

```
User.find(params[:user_id]) # returns an instance of User class
User.find(params[:user_id]).all_accounts # returns an array
```

The Array class doesn't have an instance method called `all` that's why you are seeing this error. This is not a bug.

Why don't you try this:

```
class User
  has_many :accounts, :conditions => { :active => 1 }
  has_many :all_accounts :conditions => ["(active = ? OR public = ?)", 
                           true, true]
end
```

Now you can:

```
User.find(params[:user_id]).all_accounts.all(:limit => 10, :offset => 2)
```

Comment: Updated my answer take a look.

Comment: That doesn't work.  It's not an active OR public.  It's AccountID = user.AccountID OR public.

Answer (score 0):

You're try to access two distinct tables and apply LIMIT/OFFSET to them as a combined union. That aint gonna happen unless you logically combine them at the SQL layer, not at the ActiveRecord layer.

Sounds like writing out the SQL, maybe using a `UNION` and then using `find_by_sql` might be your best best.

Comment: Seems like it might be the case.  I hate doing that... much rather have the logic in the models.

Comment: Then you might be able to write a SQL View which encapsulates your queries and makes it appear as if its a simple query which your model can execute