# concatenate two active record results (through join table) to return a new result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I have the following :

```
Account --> Options
Account --> Profiles --> Options
```

Here are the models

```
# models/account.rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts_has_options
  has_many :options, :through => :accounts_has_options
  has_many :accounts_has_profiles
  has_many :profiles, :through => :accounts_has_profiles
end

# models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles_has_options
  has_many :options, :through => :profiles_has_options
  has_many :accounts_has_options
  has_many :accounts, :through => :account_has_options
end

# models/option.rb
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts_has_options
  has_many :accounts, :through => :accounts_has_options
  has_many :profiles_has_options
  has_many :profiles, :through => :profiles_has_options
end
```

I would like to have all options associated with an Account and all options associated through profiles, maybe in a virtual attribute.

I've found an example in that question :
[How do you concatenate two active record results to return a new result that can further be filtered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437874/how-do-you-concatenate-two-active-record-results-to-return-a-new-result-that-can)
But they had only two models concerned, in my case we have a join table in the story.

Any idea, how to write such virtual attribute ?

Comment: Have you tried what that question suggests?  I don't see any particular reason why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a method like this to your Account model

```
def all_options
    profile_option_ids = []
    self.profiles.map{|p| profile_option_ids = profile_option_ids + p.options.pluck("options.id")}
    Option.where("id IN (?) or id IN (?)", self.options, profile_option_ids)
end
```

So you just have to call

```
account.all_options
```